# How to find out the regional code of a DVD in Ubuntu?

Tags: dvd, drm

I have some DVDs where the regional code is not printed on the DVD case. 
I want to sell them, so I need to know their regional code. 
Is there a tool to find out in Ubuntu / Linux?

Please note: I do not want to find out the regional code of my DVD driver but of the DVD.

Comment: the inner ring of the original DVD (on the back-side) has imprinted little ciphers and so there is the regional code engraved with laser too ?! - when I am not wrong for Germany there is "D21" or "D1" or "D2" ?! - quite small to read ...

Comment: I couldn't find anything like this on my DVDs but maybe that was because they had no regional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be somewhere on the DVD casing if it has a region lock (not all DVDs have them).

If you have the DVD inserted and start VLC from command line it will show it. Example output:

```
libdvdread: Encrypted DVD support unavailable.
************************************************
**                                            **
**  No css library available. See             **
**  /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/README.css     **
**  for more information.                     **
**                                            **
************************************************
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'fr' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: fr
```

from an DVD of Elfenlied.