# How to find out the regional code of a DVD drive in Ubuntu?

Tags: dvd

Can one figure the DVD region/s allowed by their DVD drive?

Note: I mean doing so without trial and error with [specific region-encoded DVD's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677157/how-to-find-out-the-regional-code-of-a-dvd-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt install regionset
```

insert a cd or dvd and ...

```
$ regionset
regionset version 0.1 -- reads/sets region code on DVD drives
Current Region Code settings:
RPC Phase: II
type: NONE
vendor resets available: 4
user controlled changes resets available: 5
drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF
```

Comment: Any idea why inserting a CD is required for the test?

Comment: a dvd drive can't be read if it has nothing in it.

Comment: BTW, my output is identical to yours above. any idea what should one make of `drive plays discs from region(s):, mask=0xFF` being the output of the utility? regionless? couldn't figure how to interpret the mask but I won't be going into the code for it I guess

Comment: @Rinzwind and where is region in there ?

Comment: @RS "drive plays discs from region(s):,"   The drive it was used on did not have 1 set ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind doesn't it mean any region ?